# Stanford CoreNLP and Emoji?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

So far when I tried to use emoji and using the POS tagger, it appeared as unknown symbols, small boxes. Is there a way to get the POS tagger to work with emoji? Emoji (eg ) the unicode versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the character encoding is correct throughout your code, system and the Stanford CoreNLP code, emoji should be represented correctly. However, you'll have two more fundamental problems:

First, emoji are one character long and they are unlikely to be tagged as anything other than an indefinite article. 'a' in English. A smart tokenizer might make better sense of emoji, but I doubt it.

Secondly, and more importantly, POS taggers annotate [parts of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech). Emoji are not a part of speech. In the very least, they are an independent, new class of tokens, but certainly not grammatical.

All that said ... you know their character codes ... they're already tagged.

Comment: If they're showing up as small boxes, chances are the encoding is not the same. Just a guess.

Comment: And anywhere between the original and the output terminal could be the culprit.

Comment: Very true. /length

Comment: You are right, I just went through the code again and noticed POS tagger completely ignores it and tokenizer is having issues getting the input. I think I would need to get the help of a Emoji Library for Java and interpret it separately.

Comment: "emoji are one character long" is completely wrong. An Emoji's length is up to 7!

Answer (score 3):

As of version 3.8.0, Stanford CoreNLP supports emojis.

[Release notes.](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html)

Comment: what does it mean by support emojis? I got this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905716/stanford-chinese-segmentor-dont-handle-emojis-well